# Create Discord Webhook with python

Tags: python, discord, webhooks, discord.py

**Create Discord Webhook with python**
I'm recently working on a discord bot with python. where my discord bot needs to send a message through
"DISCORD WEBHOOK". the problem is I can't found a way to create a discord webhook automatically using python! Are there any ways to do so!.

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'createhook':
        #code to create a webhook in that current channel
client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook

you need a `discord.TextChannel` object.
In your case you can get the channel of your message object with `message.channel`. [See here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)

To create a webhook you'll need to do `message.channel.create_webhook(name="mywebhook")`.

Comment: Better suggestion would be to create bot commands instead of creating webhooks on reading message.content or maybe creating slash for creating new web hooks along with passing their name or dynamic image url (with default one if not passed)